# How to find 4 byte number that was absent in input?

Tags: python, algorithm

I have such task, and actually have no idea how to start.
On the input I have a huge array of 4-byte positive numbers. Numbers can be repeated. I know that one of the number is not included in the input array. How can I find this number, using minimum resources?

Comment: You would have to have a really, really huge array if exactly one four-byte number was not included -- well over 4 billion entries.  I don't think your question is well-formed.

Comment: Do you have 500Megabytes available?  If so, you can simply use a bitmask using 1bit to represent the presence of each number

Comment: hmm, well the sum of all numbers up to some endpoint is `n(n+1)/2`, if you subtracted that from the sum of all numbers in the input you would get the missing number.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Doesn't handle duplicates.

Comment: @user2357112 right... ok I've got nothing.

Comment: How big is "huge" - in the order of millions or billions?

Comment: Are you talking about **all** 4 byte numbers, or a particular (very large) set?  If it's a subset of all numbers, you need to give us some conditions for set membership, or else there's no way to tell if a number is missing or just isn't part of the subset.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest code to do so, would probably be (in pseudo code):

```
function find_missing(input)
    sort!(input)   # in-place sort, should take most of the time
    val = 0
    for d in input    # go over sorted input
        if d == val
            val += 1
        end
        if d > val
            break
        end
    end
    return val
end
```

The above function should return the missing value or zero (in case there are no missing values because of wrap around of integers). If the missing value is zero, there is a bit of a confusion but the fix is simple and left to the reader.

Note: this is not the fastest method. Faster methods would use multiple passes to split up the input to subsets and analyze these subsets using the maximum available memory.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure whether I understand your question fully. However, from what I understand, you have an array of integers and an input (which is also integers).

```
set_of_integers = set(array_of_integers)

for input_item in input:
    if input_item not in set_of_integers:
        print(input_item)
```

In this approach, the input is not sorted, which has O(n log n) time complexity, and also, you don't store the entire input (assuming the input is coming from an external file). The only memory requirement is to hold the set of integers. If there are many redundancies in the original list of numbers, the size of the set will be significantly smaller. A set look up is O(1). Therefore, the provided solution has O(n) time complexity, where n is the number of input items.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you know what the original set of values is, so I'm going to go ahead and just assume that you have two lists of values, `set1` and `set2`, which may or may not contain duplicates, may or may not be in the same order, and differ by a single element which you wish to identify. I'm not going to worry about how the sets originated.

With that setup, you can XOR all of the data.  The result will be your missing value.  To illustrate this, I have a small demo that creates two identical lists, randomly deletes an element from the second one (and retains the value for checking), shuffles the lists, and does the XOR.

```
import random as r
from functools import reduce

def xor_all(lst):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x ^ y, lst)

set1 = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9]
r.shuffle(set1)
set2 = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,9]
rv = set2.pop(r.randrange(len(set2)))
r.shuffle(set2)

print("deleted value was: ", rv)
print("xor_all identified: ", xor_all(set1) ^ xor_all(set2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I go with Dan Getz assumption of the problem. Dan's solution gives you in the worst case O(n log n) runtime.

Now the crazy idea:
How about skipping the sorting part that is the "heaviest" overhead O(n log n)? Instead of starting with the sorting, just maintain a `Hashmap` of ALL 4 byte positive integers with integer itself as a key and `false` as the default value. 
Some pseudo code:

**start**

```
foreach number in the input:
   if the number is in the valid range:
      if the corresponding hashmap entry has the value set to `false`, toggle it to `true`
      otherwise, do nothing and skip to the next input
foreach Hashmap entry
      if the value is `false` return the key of that entry
```

**end**

The size of the Hashmap is smaller or equal to the size of the input (n).
The runtime complexity in the worst case O(n)
Memory-wise you will need an additional O(n) of memory. Most likely it will be worse than for Dan Gretz solution (depends what sorting algorithm he uses, if I assume the normal Merge sort, then probably my solution will waste more memory most of the time and will waste the same or less amount of memory only during the last step of merge sort)